# Should I create objects within the json parser

Tags: android, json, performance, oop

One part of my android application requires to generate a form with a big amount of checkboxs(more than a hunderd) and text fields. All of these have been break down into sections and subsections. I have created a json configuration file to store the format of the form.

Something like:

```
  "sections":[
       {
            "title":"sectionA"
            "type":"check_box|number"
            "items":[
                  {
                      "title"="itemAA"
                      "type"="check_box"
                  },
                   ...
              ]
        },
        ...
  ]
```

Now my question is that when I am parsing this json object, should I create the objects as I am paring the configuration file or I should store all the information into a arraylist or hashmap then pass it to other object so the new objects will be created outside the parser?

Comment: ...are you writing your own parser instead of using an existing one?

Comment: It doesn't sound as though you will exhaust memory, but it sounds as though you are on the deciding side of choosing between something like a SAX parser or DOM model structure for handling your parsing.  Whatever best suits your needs should be fine.

Comment: Just parse it once and pass around the JSON. There's no real difference in terms of efficiency when geting something from a JSONObject vs. an ArrayList

Comment: @Izkata I am thinking about write my own SAX parser? As the form can be really heavy and I dont want use to much of the memory space.